# How to crop a JPEG without recompressing?

Tags: jpg, crop, compression, jpeg

Is it possible to crop a JPEG image without losing quality or recompressing the remaining part of the image?

Comment: I don't think cropping a image loses the quality of it.

Comment: Not in itself. However, if the image editor you are using is not smart enough, when it comes to saving the cropped image, it could easily re-compress an already compressed image, which would be needless and result in image loss. I'm wondering if it's possible avoid this.

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of software you use? for image editing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[FreeVImager](http://www.contaware.com/freevimager.html) can do this with nice GUI.
[image: Lossless crop menu]
[image: Lossless crop operation]

It also can do lossless rotation of JPEGs (90 deg rotations are loseless).
It's FOSS, so if you're on Linux, it's worth getting Wine for one.

Comment: Hmm... I tried this and the current version matches your illustration.  But I can't find an "accept" or "done" control to use after moving the rectangle to the desired position.

Comment: @JDługosz just press Enter :) (the tip in status line) Also, author is communicable and gladly responds emails. You can tell him ;-)

Comment: Wow, house of my sister in Stack Exchange :) . Thanks, if I use FreeVimager, I can crop big-size `jpg`; if I use GIMP, I can't do it.

Comment: This program is snapping the bottom and right sides to iMCU boundaries despite it being unnecessary and restrictive. IrfanView worked better for me.

Comment: The cropped image is bigger in size then the original image, using the Lossless Crop toll in FreeVImager 9.9.10. So it's useless...

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea I've stopped on 7.7.0 as it's last one actually free (newer ones are shareware). And I didn't see size increase with my photos. Can you give an example? Maybe you've re-saved the photo (thus recompressed it) after losslessly cropping? Anyway, lossless crop is not to "decrease file size", it's to avoid quality loss due to recompression while removing some parts of a picture, therefore, even if size increases, it's not useless.

Comment: @LogicDaemon, I open a jpeg image, 4000x6400 pixels and about 3.54 MB, in FreeVImager. Using the tool JPEG Advanced -> Lossless crop, I select an area of 3360x6056 pixels and then I press Enter: the result is an image of 3360x6056 pixels (-20%) and 4.10 MB (+16%). Or, with the same image, cropping lossless to 3888x6304 (-4%) the result image is 4.14 MB in size (+17%). Anyway you are right, probably it's not completely useless. You will find the test image file and the cropped ones at https://mega.nz/folder/C7gjETYZ#LsqBhwU92MaSRIHQr6nV5A

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea I've verified, same effect of size increase for me with ver 7.7.0. No idea if that's result of some original image optimizations, or a bug in FVI when cropping 8-bit grayscale JPEGs. Never even seen such jpegs in the wild before.

Answer (score 19):

Lossless cropping of a JPEG image is possible using the
 "jpegtran" application that comes with libjpeg; see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg.

Quoting from "man jpegtran" on a system where jpegtran is installed:

> .. lossless crop is restricted by the current JPEG format: the upper
>   left corner of the selected region must fall on an iMCU [8 or 16]
>   boundary. If this does not hold for the given crop parameters, we
>   silently move the upper left corner up and/or left to make it so,
>   simultaneously increasing the region dimensions to keep the lower
>   right crop corner unchanged. (Thus, the output image covers at
>   least the requested region, but may cover more.)

With other image-editing software you can minimize the loss by ensuring that the cropped area has dimensions that are multiples of 8 and is located with offsets being some multiple of 8 (or 16, if the colors were subsampled) from the upper lefthand corner of the original image, and that the compression "quality" is the same as that of the original image.

Comment: The wiki says "cropping at image block borders (every 8×8 or 16×16 pixels)." Does the tool limit you to these boundaries in order to make this possible? I *guess* from your note about mitigating lossage in other programs that the answer is "yes" (?)

Comment: Sometimes the multiple must be 16 instead of 8. JPEG allows subsampling of the color information, which means the 8x8 blocks for those color components will actually cover 16x16 pixels.

Comment: @MarkRansom right, thanks.  I expanded the answer to mention "or 16"

Comment: How do you determine if the iMCU is 8 or 16 in linux?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit you could run ImageMagick's "identify -verbose" or some other JPEG examination tool and look for the "sampling factors".

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson: I got *jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1* What does that mean?

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson: I guess MCU=8 only when jpeg:sampling-factor=1x1,1x1,1x1, otherwise MCU=16?

Answer (score 8):

[Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/) has lossless JPG cropping and rotation functions:

[image]

Comment: This is accessed in the menu with Options -> JPG Lossless Crop... (PlugIn).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Photoshop® then I don't believe that the image compresses when it crops. The compression happens when you ***resave*** the document as a JPG. It is always best to start with the highest lossless uncompressed image format you can such as .NEF, .BMP... others (?) As the saying goes, poop in poop out.

Comment: I don't think it is as you think. I think Photoshop can't do crop without recompression.

Comment: @Royi - no. Photoshop can crop the jpeg without recompression, the problem is when you resave it as jpeg. Compression will be added again. If you export as PNG instead, you can avoid this issue entirely, since PNGs are lossless.